# How to properly check if I can do toString

Tags: javascript

Usually this code works just like expected, but sometimes it throws an error. It also doesn't feel like a proper way to do it. I am also wondering how to properly do this.

```
if (qIdAnswer && qIdAnswer.hasOwnProperty('Numeric')) {
    answer = parseFloat(qIdAnswer.Numeric.toString().replace(',', '.'));
} else {
    answer = parseFloat(qIdAnswer.OpenText.replace(',', '.'));
}
```

As you can see, the to-be-transformed input can be in 1 of 2 locations. It can also be `0`, which is accepted, therefore I do `hasOwnProperty()`

The error I get:

```
null is not an object (evaluating 'qIdAnswer.Numeric.toString');
```

As this code is used on a backend, I do not have access to the DOM.

I am also working with multiple types of input, so the decimal can be either a dot `.` or comma `,`. That is why I am converting it to a generic output. The `OpenText` property is always set, that is checked before this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's telling you that `qIdAnswer.Numeric` exists and has the value `null`. You'd get the same problem with `undefined`. You can defend against both of those by doing a further `!= null` check (which will defend against both):

```
if (qIdAnswer && qIdAnswer.hasOwnProperty('Numeric') && qIdAnswer.Numeric != null) {
    answer = parseFloat(qIdAnswer.Numeric.toString().replace(',', '.'));
} else {
    answer = parseFloat(qIdAnswer.OpenText.replace(',', '.'));
}
```

or if you worry about the maintainability of `!= null` checks and `undefined` values (e.g., programmers who don't know that it will handle `undefined`), be explicit:

```
if (qIdAnswer && qIdAnswer.hasOwnProperty('Numeric') && qIdAnswer.Numeric !== null && qIdAnswer.Numeric !== undefined) {
    answer = parseFloat(qIdAnswer.Numeric.toString().replace(',', '.'));
} else {
    answer = parseFloat(qIdAnswer.OpenText.replace(',', '.'));
}
```

Comment: great catch. How could I forget. Testing as we speak